# Accessing Class Properties with Spaces

Tags: php, oop, class, codeigniter, properties

`stdClass Object ([Sector] => Manufacturing [Date Found] => 2010-05-03 08:15:19)`

So I can access `[Sector]` by using `$object->Sector` but how can I access `[Date Found]` ?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$object->{'Date Found'}
```

Answer (score 16):

have you tried

```
$property = 'Date Found';
$object->{$property};
```

Or simply

```
$object->{'Date Found'};
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
$var="Date Found"; $this->$var
```

But I doubt that much you can have spaces in class properties names in php

Comment: heck, what do you know...it works...anyway, I wouldn't use spaces in the properties names :)