# How to access an array from within an object?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing Class Properties with Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027615/accessing-class-properties-with-spaces)

i have and object file and i cant get devices list, How to get **devices**?? how to call 2 wards like "Canon Camera" ?

```
  [Camera] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Canon Camera] => stdClass Object
            (
                [DEVICES] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Canon EOS 30
                        [1] => Canon EOS 5D Mark II
                        [2] => Canon EOS 7D
                        [3] => Canon EOS A2
                        [4] => Canon EOS Digital Rebel (300D)
                        [5] => Canon EOS Rebel XS
                        [6] => Canon PowerShot 1200
                        [7] => Canon PowerShot A200
                        [8] => Canon PowerShot A520
                        [9] => Canon PowerShot A550


                    )

            )
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027615/accessing-class-properties-with-spaces

Comment: Whats that object for? Looks like an assoc. array to my with only "DEVICES" as key. Use an array and the usual foreach loop. Or access it with quotes.

Comment: @Qchmqs - and what about your profile info ? `(...) u can clearly see how mush experience (...)`. Your comment is inappropriate.

Comment: i am not insulting him i just don't understand the question even if i want to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$object->Camera->{'Canon Camera'}->DEVICES
```

Then you will have an access to `DEVICES` array.

```
foreach ( $object->Camera->{'Canon Camera'}->DEVICES as $device ) {
  echo $device . <br/>;
}
```

Comment: +1 but some explanation might be nice for OP's benefit

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces in the array, make `Canon Camera` for example `canon_camera`

After that, you can open it like:

```
$camera->canon_camera->DEVICES
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$object->Camera->{'Canon Camera'}->DEVICES
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to do something like this?:

```
foreach($devices_list->Camera->{'Canon Camera'}->DEVICES as $key => $value) {
  echo $value."\n";
}
```