# How to decode json string into half array/ half object?

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode, icws

I have the following json string

```
$str = '{"icwsCallQueue":{"1002598152":{"AccoRDI_account_id":"","AccoRDI_mid":"","Eic_CallDirection":"O","Eic_CallIdKey":"100259815260150624","Eic_CallState":"Disconnected","Eic_ConferenceId":"","Eic_ConferenceMembers":"","Eic_ImmediateAccess":"1","Eic_LocalName":"Full Name","Eic_LocalUserId":"username","Eic_MonitorsCombinedCount":"0","Eic_Muted":"","Eic_ObjectType":"Call","Eic_ParentConferenceId":"","Eic_RemoteAddress":"307","Eic_RemoteName":"username-test","Eic_State":"I"},"1002598162":{"AccoRDI_account_id":"","AccoRDI_mid":"","Eic_CallDirection":"O","Eic_CallIdKey":"100259816260150624","Eic_CallState":"Disconnected","Eic_ConferenceId":"","Eic_ConferenceMembers":"","Eic_ImmediateAccess":"1","Eic_LocalName":"Full Name","Eic_LocalUserId":"username","Eic_MonitorsCombinedCount":"0","Eic_Muted":"","Eic_ObjectType":"Call","Eic_ParentConferenceId":"","Eic_RemoteAddress":"307","Eic_RemoteName":"username-test","Eic_State":"I"}}}';
```

If I decode it using `json_decode($str)`
I get the following

```
stdClass Object
(
    [icwsCallQueue] => stdClass Object
        (
            [1002598152] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [AccoRDI_account_id] => 
                    [AccoRDI_mid] => 
                    [Eic_CallDirection] => O
                    [Eic_CallIdKey] => 100259815260150624
                    [Eic_CallState] => Disconnected
                    [Eic_ConferenceId] => 
                    [Eic_ConferenceMembers] => 
                    [Eic_ImmediateAccess] => 1
                    [Eic_LocalName] => Full Name
                    [Eic_LocalUserId] => username
                    [Eic_MonitorsCombinedCount] => 0
                    [Eic_Muted] => 
                    [Eic_ObjectType] => Call
                    [Eic_ParentConferenceId] => 
                    [Eic_RemoteAddress] => 307
                    [Eic_RemoteName] => username-test
                    [Eic_State] => I
                )

            [1002598162] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [AccoRDI_account_id] => 
                    [AccoRDI_mid] => 
                    [Eic_CallDirection] => O
                    [Eic_CallIdKey] => 100259816260150624
                    [Eic_CallState] => Disconnected
                    [Eic_ConferenceId] => 
                    [Eic_ConferenceMembers] => 
                    [Eic_ImmediateAccess] => 1
                    [Eic_LocalName] => Full Name
                    [Eic_LocalUserId] => username
                    [Eic_MonitorsCombinedCount] => 0
                    [Eic_Muted] => 
                    [Eic_ObjectType] => Call
                    [Eic_ParentConferenceId] => 
                    [Eic_RemoteAddress] => 307
                    [Eic_RemoteName] => username-test
                    [Eic_State] => I
                )

        )

)
```

The problem with this is that I can't access a property with only an integer. I can't do this `$icwsCallQueue->100259152->Eic_State`
so what I need to do some how is convert my decoded string to something like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [icwsCallQueue] => Array
        (
            [1002598152] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [AccoRDI_account_id] => 
                    [AccoRDI_mid] => 
                    [Eic_CallDirection] => O
                    [Eic_CallIdKey] => 100259815260150624
                    [Eic_CallState] => Disconnected
                    [Eic_ConferenceId] => 
                    [Eic_ConferenceMembers] => 
                    [Eic_ImmediateAccess] => 1
                    [Eic_LocalName] => Full Name
                    [Eic_LocalUserId] => username
                    [Eic_MonitorsCombinedCount] => 0
                    [Eic_Muted] => 
                    [Eic_ObjectType] => Call
                    [Eic_ParentConferenceId] => 
                    [Eic_RemoteAddress] => 307
                    [Eic_RemoteName] => username-test
                    [Eic_State] => I
                )

            [1002598162] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [AccoRDI_account_id] => 
                    [AccoRDI_mid] => 
                    [Eic_CallDirection] => O
                    [Eic_CallIdKey] => 100259816260150624
                    [Eic_CallState] => Disconnected
                    [Eic_ConferenceId] => 
                    [Eic_ConferenceMembers] => 
                    [Eic_ImmediateAccess] => 1
                    [Eic_LocalName] => Full Name
                    [Eic_LocalUserId] => username
                    [Eic_MonitorsCombinedCount] => 0
                    [Eic_Muted] => 
                    [Eic_ObjectType] => Call
                    [Eic_ParentConferenceId] => 
                    [Eic_RemoteAddress] => 307
                    [Eic_RemoteName] => username-test
                    [Eic_State] => I
                )

        )

)
```

so I can access the records like this `$icwsCallQueue['100259152']->Eic_State`

on the other hand if I decoded the string like this `json_decode($str, true)` everything will be presented as array which is not what am I looking for.

Any idea on how to decode the string with array when array must be used and object when array can be avoided?

Comment: Try this maybe? `$icwsCallQueue->{100259152}->Eic_State`. Additionally, can you access the object via index ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027615/accessing-class-properties-with-spaces  works for any "illegal" key names.

Comment: if you do not need to access `$icwsCallQueue` properties directly you can iterate over then.

Comment: Or you could also just cast the parts you want to become an array (per `settype()` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast array to stdclass and stdclass to array when needed.

First of all `json_decode($str, true)` to get the associative version of the data. 
Then  iterate through  the most inner parts of the data and cast arrays back to objects again. Now it's possible to use stdclass properties as accessors.

```
  $str = '{"icwsCallQueue":{"1002598152":{"AccoRDI_account_id":"","AccoRDI_mid":"","Eic_CallDirection":"O","Eic_CallIdKey":"100259815260150624","Eic_CallState":"Disconnected","Eic_ConferenceId":"","Eic_ConferenceMembers":"","Eic_ImmediateAccess":"1","Eic_LocalName":"Full Name","Eic_LocalUserId":"username","Eic_MonitorsCombinedCount":"0","Eic_Muted":"","Eic_ObjectType":"Call","Eic_ParentConferenceId":"","Eic_RemoteAddress":"307","Eic_RemoteName":"username-test","Eic_State":"I"},"1002598162":{"AccoRDI_account_id":"","AccoRDI_mid":"","Eic_CallDirection":"O","Eic_CallIdKey":"100259816260150624","Eic_CallState":"Disconnected","Eic_ConferenceId":"","Eic_ConferenceMembers":"","Eic_ImmediateAccess":"1","Eic_LocalName":"Full Name","Eic_LocalUserId":"username","Eic_MonitorsCombinedCount":"0","Eic_Muted":"","Eic_ObjectType":"Call","Eic_ParentConferenceId":"","Eic_RemoteAddress":"307","Eic_RemoteName":"username-test","Eic_State":"I"}}}';
  $json = json_decode($str, true);
  foreach($json["icwsCallQueue"] as $key => $element) {
    $json["icwsCallQueue"][$key] = (object)$element;
  }
  var_dump($json["icwsCallQueue"]['1002598152']->Eic_CallIdKey);
  var_dump($json["icwsCallQueue"]['1002598162']->Eic_CallIdKey);
```

There was another and simpler solution but I couldn't make it work. That's why I have to iterate all the array.

```
  $str = '{"icwsCallQueue":{"1002598152":{"AccoRDI_account_id":"","AccoRDI_mid":"","Eic_CallDirection":"O","Eic_CallIdKey":"100259815260150624","Eic_CallState":"Disconnected","Eic_ConferenceId":"","Eic_ConferenceMembers":"","Eic_ImmediateAccess":"1","Eic_LocalName":"Full Name","Eic_LocalUserId":"username","Eic_MonitorsCombinedCount":"0","Eic_Muted":"","Eic_ObjectType":"Call","Eic_ParentConferenceId":"","Eic_RemoteAddress":"307","Eic_RemoteName":"username-test","Eic_State":"I"},"1002598162":{"AccoRDI_account_id":"","AccoRDI_mid":"","Eic_CallDirection":"O","Eic_CallIdKey":"100259816260150624","Eic_CallState":"Disconnected","Eic_ConferenceId":"","Eic_ConferenceMembers":"","Eic_ImmediateAccess":"1","Eic_LocalName":"Full Name","Eic_LocalUserId":"username","Eic_MonitorsCombinedCount":"0","Eic_Muted":"","Eic_ObjectType":"Call","Eic_ParentConferenceId":"","Eic_RemoteAddress":"307","Eic_RemoteName":"username-test","Eic_State":"I"}}}';
  $json = json_decode($str);
  $jsonArray = (array)$json->icwsCallQueue;
  var_dump($jsonArray["1002598152"]);
  //PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1002598152 in
```

Looks like PHP does not cast to array properly with integer keys. Or there is something I am missing here.

The rest is up to your imagination.