# Reading API response in PHP

Tags: php

I am making a request to mixpanel API

```
$data = $mp->request(array('segmentation'), array(
    'event' => 'Loaded a Page',
    'name' => 'Loaded a Page',
    'from_date' => '2015-07-01',
    'to_date' => '2015-07-01',
    'type' => 'unique',   
    'expire' => '1439089200'
    //'unit' => 'day',
    //'interval' => '7',
    //'format' => 'json'
));
//echo $data;
var_dump($data);
```

Here is the response I am getting.

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) { ["legend_size"]=> int(1) ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) 
{ ["series"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "2015-07-01" } ["values"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) 
{ ["Loaded a Page"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["2015-07-01"]=> int(267691) } } } }
```

Can anyone please help me with how can I read the response in variables. Say I want to get the count of Loaded a Page event for '2015-07-01' from the response.

Comment: it's an object/array like any other. just because it came from an api doesn't make it special - you access things in it exactly the same way you do in any other php object/array.

Answer (score 1):

> Say I want to get the count of Loaded a Page event for '2015-07-01' from the response.

```
$data->values->{"Loaded a Page"}->{"2015-07-01"}
```

Please note, this is a very nasty format. I would check if `request()` takes parameters to adjust the format.

Nonetheless, I'd encourage you to read about [Objects Properties in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and this answer [Accessing Class Properties with Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027615/accessing-class-properties-with-spaces).

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for the response but its not working. I tried to break it and echo like $data->{'values'} or $data->{'values'} -> {'Loaded a Page'} or $data->{'values'}-> {'Loaded a Page'}  -> {'2015-07-01'}.. None of these are echoing anything.

Comment: It's difficult to read the output unformatted, but this should put you on the right track.