# Issue with JSON key with spaces

Tags: php, json

So `Team` name outputs correctly for me however `Number of Days` does not.

```
    $json = json_decode($response);

    $results = $json->Result;

    foreach($results as $item) {
    
        echo $item["Number of Days"];
        echo '<br>';
        echo $item->Team;
        echo '<hr>';
    }
```

Do I have to do something different for outputting when the key has spaces in it?

Comment: @tanaydin — This is PHP, not JavaScript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027615/accessing-class-properties-with-spaces

Comment: `echo $item->{'Number of Days'}`

Comment: @ChrisLear Wow. Thank you so so much. Feel free to make as an Answer and I'll green tick :-)

Comment: Or decode as array and then do array access.