# How to access value of this kind of object

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I want to access `-value` I tried `$token->value`, `$token->getValue()` I'm not sure how to access this please someone help me

```
$token=Tymon\JWTAuth\Token {#1960
          -value: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vd29ya3BvcnRhbC5sb2NhbC9hcGkvdjEvYXV0aGVudGljYXRlLXBpbiIsImlhdCI6MTYyMDIwMzQzOSwiZXhwIjoxNjIwNDYyNjM5LCJuYmYiOjE2MjAyMDM0MzksImp0aSI6IkdmOFJjSWRubk13MHdoeEkiLCJzdWIiOjEsInBydiI6Ijg3ZTBhZjFlZjlmZDE1ODEyZmRlYzk3MTUzYTE0ZTBiMDQ3NTQ2YWEifQ.y8ddEfcV3Gf703onpu2YmX0n7FcHUq78JEW6eOr9Rhs"
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Class Properties with Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027615/accessing-class-properties-with-spaces)

Comment: Or [Special characters in property name of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455775/special-characters-in-property-name-of-object)

Comment: if the attribute is public, you can do it with the dupplicated answer. if you're looking for a declared method, use `get_class_methods($token)` to get a list of available methods on that object. it should be ->payload btw

Comment: N69S your solution worked for me since my object value is private I can't use that duplicate answer and your method gave me all the available methods which I can use to access the value thank you very much.

Comment: The `-` in front of the `value` means it's private, which means the developers of that library don't want you to access that variable. Perhaps looking into the documentation of that library you can find an alternative way to access the data correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$token = auth()->tokenById($userId);`

From documentation of library which you use:
https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/auth-guard/

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why and how it solves the issue, so that any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: I got an answer already from the above comment by N69S